# How to return value unquoted in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ibm-watson

I am trying to implement Watson callback function in Ruby on Rails and they say I should omit the quote in the return.

I created get method to return what was received. The url is "http://someurl/api/v1/resoucename/results?somevalue=123123", I return 123123 as "123123"

```
resource :resoucename do 
   get :results do 
     return params[:somevalue]
   end
end
```

How can I return a unquoted value?

Watson says:
*The request includes an Accept header that specifies text/plain as the required response type.*

If anyone has an idea how to return as it is, please share with me!
Best

Comment: Which Watson API are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `"123123"` then you have an string, an integer would be unquoted, like:

```
p "123123"
# => "123123"
p "123123".to_i
# => 123123
```

So most probably you could "tweak" your method to:

```
resource :resoucename do 
  get :results do 
    params[:somevalue].to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, what if the somevalue is something like 11kc02jxcaw2?

Comment: Oh, you're totally right, your `somevalue` is it something like `'"11kc02jxcaw2"'`, what about using [`gsub`](http://ideone.com/9QY69m)?